# Using MAX() with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server

I have a history table and I want to get the latest modification of one employee.
I have this example, the max always brings one record?

```
 CREATE TABLE EmployeeHIST
 (
 Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
 EmployeeId INT,
 FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
 LastName NVARCHAR(50),
 ModifiedDate DATETIME
 )

 INSERT INTO EmployeeHIST VALUES (1, 1, 'Jhon', 'Doo', '2013-01-24 23:45:12')
 INSERT INTO EmployeeHIST VALUES (2, 1, 'Jhon', 'Doo', '2013-02-24 15:45:12')
 INSERT INTO EmployeeHIST VALUES (3, 1, 'Jhon', 'Doo', '2013-02-24 15:45:12')

SELECT EmployeeId, MAX([ModifiedDate])
FROM EmployeeHIST
WHERE EmployeeId = 1
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

Ok yes, you are right, but in case I need to get the Id column for EmployeeId = 1, in this case I will receive two values 2 and 3, so I need to apply a top one right?

Comment: The MAX brings one record for each of the combination of values defined in Group By. In your sample data, yes always one record. If you were Group By Id,EmployeeId you would get three records as there are three unique combinations of those values. This also applies for other aggregation functions as Min(), Avg(),Count() etc

Comment: Why `MAX()` should bring different result? max will be always max? And I am not sure why you use MAX() in this case?

Comment: What did you *expect* to happen, if receiving one result seems to have surprised you?

Comment: With the data you have given, MAX will return only one record. What else are you trying to do? Sorting in descending order of modified date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Max()** brings one record for each of the combination of values defined in Group By.

In your sample data, yes always one record.

If you were Group By Id,EmployeeId you would get three records as there are three unique combinations of those values.

This also applies for other aggregation functions as **Min()**, **Avg()**, **Count()** etc

**UPDATE**
If you want to get the id of the record that has the max(date) then you have the following option (there may be better ones):

```
;With MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT EmployeeId, MAX([ModifiedDate]) AS MaxDate
    FROM EmployeeHIST
    GROUP BY EmployeeId
)
SELECT E.Id,E.EmployeeId,ModifiedDate
FROM   EmployeeHIST E
       JOIN MyCTE M
           ON M.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
           AND M.MaxDate = E.ModifiedDate
WHERE  E.EmployeeId = 1
```

**[SQLFiddle 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebf52/2)**

Now, in this case you have both ids 2 and 3 returned. I do not know what is the business requirement here, but i believe you would want only 3 to be returned, so the next is a solution:

```
;With MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT EmployeeId, MAX([ModifiedDate]) AS MaxDate
    FROM EmployeeHIST
    GROUP BY EmployeeId
)
SELECT MAX(E.Id),E.EmployeeId,ModifiedDate
FROM   EmployeeHIST E
       JOIN MyCTE M
           ON M.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
           AND M.MaxDate = E.ModifiedDate
WHERE  E.EmployeeId = 1
GROUP BY E.EmployeeId,ModifiedDate
```

**[SQLFiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebf52/4)**